# Copying select Excel charts to locations in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

From Excel, I need to open a PowerPoint template, walk each slide and using some data in the alternative text field of the placeholders, match them to a chart in Excel and copy it to that location in the PowerPoint slide.

After searching I found some code, which I have modified to achieve my goal. It works in Win7 Enterprise, but when I run this same exact code in Win10 Enterprise, I get the following error:

```
System Error &H800706BE (-2147023170). The remote procedure call failed.
```

Below is my code, any assistance in what I may be doing wrong or what may have changed in Win10 that is causing my problem would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm running Office 365 ProPlus.

```
Public Sub QBR_Deck()

    '#
    '# Set reference to 'Microsoft PowerPoint <current version> Object Library' in the VBE via Tools > References...
    '#

    '#
    '# Declare variables
    '#
    Dim app_PowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppt_Presentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim obj_PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim obj_PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape

    Dim obj_ExcelChart As Chart
    Dim obj_ExcelWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim obj_ExcelObject As ListObject

    Dim lng_i As Long
    Dim var_Parameters As Variant

    Dim str_PPTTemplatePath As String

    '#
    '# Allow user to select PPT template
    '# Set path to same location as spreadsheet
    '#
    str_PPTTemplatePath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="PowerPoint Template")
    If str_PPTTemplatePath = "False" Then Exit Sub

    '#
    '# Get the PowerPoint Application object
    '#
    Set app_PowerPoint = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    app_PowerPoint.Visible = msoTrue
    Set ppt_Presentation = app_PowerPoint.Presentations.Open(str_PPTTemplatePath, untitled:=msoTrue)

    '#
    '# Review each slide and each shape on slide
    '#
    For Each obj_PPTSlide In ppt_Presentation.Slides
        For Each obj_PPTShape In obj_PPTSlide.Shapes

            '#
            '# Determine when target shapes are located
            '# Examine Alternative Text in PPT
            '# Text for objects, will be in this format: @REPLACE|XLS_<chart_name>|PPT_<shape_Name>
            '#
            If Left$(obj_PPTShape.AlternativeText, 8) = "@REPLACE" Then
                var_Parameters = Split(obj_PPTShape.AlternativeText, "|")

                For Each obj_ExcelWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    '#
                    '# Look at each chart on each worksheet
                    '# Use the Alternative Text to match each chart to the appropriate slide
                    '# Copy and paste onto slide
                    '#
                    For lng_i = obj_ExcelWorksheet.ChartObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
                       If obj_ExcelWorksheet.ChartObjects(lng_i).Name = var_Parameters(1) Then
                           obj_PPTSlide.Select
                           Set obj_ExcelChart = obj_ExcelWorksheet.ChartObjects(lng_i).Chart
                           obj_ExcelChart.ChartArea.Copy
                           app_PowerPoint.Activate
                           obj_PPTShape.Select
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).View.Paste
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Left = obj_PPTShape.Left
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Top = obj_PPTShape.Top
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Height = obj_PPTShape.Height
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Width = obj_PPTShape.Width
                           obj_PPTShape.Delete
                       End If
                    Next lng_i

                Next obj_ExcelWorksheet

            End If 'Alternative Text not in expected format
        Next obj_PPTShape
    Next obj_PPTSlide

    '#
    '# Clean up on the way out
    '#
    Set ppt_Presentation = Nothing
    Set app_PowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Office 2016 Pro Plus, Windows 10 (not Office 365 but shouldn't matter).

I notice that when you use `For Each obj_PPTShape In obj_PPTSlide.Shapes` and then delete the shape, it destroys the looping. The second time through the loop, it is still thinking of the first shape, which has been deleted.

So I introduced a shape counter, and started from `obj_PPTSlide.Shapes.Count` and worked backwards (which you didn't really need ot do with the charts on the Excel slides, BTW). I also inserted `Exit For` right after deleting the shape, so you don't keep looping through charts and somehow can't find the shape that you've deleted. This might not be a problem for you, but when I copied my first chart to make a second, and changed the chart name, the new name didn't take the first time.

So here's the slightly adjusted code:

```
Public Sub QBR_Deck()

    '#
    '# Set reference to 'Microsoft PowerPoint <current version> Object Library' in the VBE via Tools > References...
    '#

    '#
    '# Declare variables
    '#
    Dim app_PowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppt_Presentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim obj_PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim obj_PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape

    Dim obj_ExcelChart As Chart
    Dim obj_ExcelWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim obj_ExcelObject As ListObject

    Dim lng_i As Long
    Dim shp_i As Long
    Dim var_Parameters As Variant

    Dim str_PPTTemplatePath As String

    '#
    '# Allow user to select PPT template
    '# Set path to same location as spreadsheet
    '#
    str_PPTTemplatePath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="PowerPoint Template")
    If str_PPTTemplatePath = "False" Then Exit Sub

    '#
    '# Get the PowerPoint Application object
    '#
    Set app_PowerPoint = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    app_PowerPoint.Visible = msoTrue
    Set ppt_Presentation = app_PowerPoint.Presentations.Open(str_PPTTemplatePath, untitled:=msoTrue)

    '#
    '# Review each slide and each shape on slide
    '#
    For Each obj_PPTSlide In ppt_Presentation.Slides
        For shp_i = obj_PPTSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set obj_PPTShape = obj_PPTSlide.Shapes(shp_i)

            '#
            '# Determine when target shapes are located
            '# Examine Alternative Text in PPT
            '# Text for objects, will be in this format: @REPLACE|XLS_<chart_name>|PPT_<shape_Name>
            '#
            If Left$(obj_PPTShape.AlternativeText, 8) = "@REPLACE" Then
                var_Parameters = Split(obj_PPTShape.AlternativeText, "|")

                For Each obj_ExcelWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    '#
                    '# Look at each chart on each worksheet
                    '# Use the Alternative Text to match each chart to the appropriate slide
                    '# Copy and paste onto slide
                    '#
                    For lng_i = obj_ExcelWorksheet.ChartObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
                       If obj_ExcelWorksheet.ChartObjects(lng_i).Name = var_Parameters(1) Then
                           obj_PPTSlide.Select
                           Set obj_ExcelChart = obj_ExcelWorksheet.ChartObjects(lng_i).Chart
                           obj_ExcelChart.ChartArea.Copy
                           ''app_PowerPoint.Activate '''' unnecessary
                           ''obj_PPTShape.Select '''' unnecessary
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).View.Paste
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Left = obj_PPTShape.Left
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Top = obj_PPTShape.Top
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Height = obj_PPTShape.Height
                           app_PowerPoint.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Width = obj_PPTShape.Width
                           obj_PPTShape.Delete
                           Exit For
                       End If
                    Next lng_i

                Next obj_ExcelWorksheet

            End If 'Alternative Text not in expected format
        Next shp_i
    Next obj_PPTSlide

    '#
    '# Clean up on the way out
    '#
    Set ppt_Presentation = Nothing
    Set app_PowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I do this I often use a table on a worksheet in Excel, and the table lists each item to be copied and pasted: source (sheet name and chart name or range address), target (slide number, shape name or simply position and size parameters), slide title if desired, etc. I find it's easier to keep all of the information in one place, the Excel workbook, rather than having to go into PowerPoint and muck with the Alt text (and you didn't even use the PowerPoint shape name, which is only accessible via VBA). Though I've never used the Alt text, and perhaps this makes it easier than how I've struggled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however, it is still crashing on Win10.  I did try running on Win7 and as usual it worked great.  I should point out that I have about 19 charts that I want to paste throughout a PPT and on Win10 it only gets through 3 before it blows up.

What's really weird is that I can place a msgbox / breakpoint in my code to see what's going on and it all looks fine AND it ends up working on Win10.  Like it's some kind of timing issue.

Comment: As I continue to test more it seems to be something with how I paste.  Currently I use ...View.Paste, and I use that because it pastes in the chart, keeps the link, and allows the user to still have formatting control over the chart in PPT.  However, if I change to ...View.PasteSpecial ppPasteMetafilePicture which of course pastes a picture, it works just fine in Win10, however, now has no further formatting control.

Comment: Might be an issue with the installation of Office on the Windows 10 machine. Go to Control Panel > Programs, select the entry for Office, and click Change above the list. Try the quick repair, and if that gives no joy, try the nore extensive repair.

Comment: I don't feel it's an installation thing as colleagues who try to run on Win10 fail as I have described above.  How may charts did you try in your testing?  I have at least 25 charts to copy and again on Win7 it runs flawless, on Win10 I typically fail after just a few copies (3-6).  Again as I mentioned if I change the paste method it work.  Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I missed your mention of a timing issue. When this seems to be the case, sometimes you can avoid it by inserting one line, `DoEvents` before the line that seems to cause the crash. This makes VBA slow down while Windows does all the stupid little things that get in the way: redrawing windows, creating the new object in PowerPoint that holds the chart, etc.